# How to reset a rabbitmq node to get rid of an enabled feature flag

Tags: rabbitmq, messagebroker

It happened after restart of a node in cluster. It complains about ***incompatible_feature_flags*** and stops. The doc says that once a feature flag enabled it is impossible to disable. The only other running node in cluster has that flag (`user_limit`) disabled and once this newly started node completes syncing tables from peer it says in the log that

```
Application mnesia exited with reason: stopped

BOOT FAILED
===========
Error during startup: {error,
                          {incompatible_feature_flags,
                              {not_active,
                                  "All replicas on diskfull nodes are not active yet",
                                  rabbit_user,
                                  [rabbit@rabbitmq3]}}}
```

I also tried by killing all process relating to rabbit server (including erlang one) and editing `rabbit@rabbitmq1-feature_flags` before start, but it gets overridden and no success.
I prefer not to enable `user_limit` feature flag on the running node and remove it on this node whatever it takes. How can I reset this node (for example by removing `mnesia` directory or else) to forget about its already enabled flag and then join it to the cluster again.

PS: rabbit@rabbitmq3 is also another node in cluster that is down and causing no harm.

Answer (score 11):

If you are using brew to run rabbit and don't care about your state, then run the following commands:

```
brew services stop rabbitmq
brew uninstall rabbitmq
rm -rf /usr/local/var/lib/rabbitmq
rm -rf /usr/local/var/log/rabbitmq
rm -rf /usr/local/etc/rabbitmq
brew install rabbitmq
brew services start rabbitmq
```

Answer (score 6):

### for MacOS Apple chip with homebrew

```
brew services stop rabbitmq
brew uninstall rabbitmq

rm -r /opt/homebrew/etc/rabbitmq                
rm -r /opt/homebrew/var/lib/rabbitmq
rm -r /opt/homebrew/var/log/rabbitmq

brew update
brew install rabbitmq
brew services start rabbitmq
```

[See the error logs I encountered](https://medium.com/@anjantalatatam/how-to-clean-install-rabbitmq-1ae214436b7d)

[Answer for MacOS intel chip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75238275/14853666)

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Ubuntu and don't care about logs, configs, data, etc., you can use `sudo apt-get purge rabbitmq-server` to remove everything and then re-install whichever version you need.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about other circumstances but in my case the culprit was the other down node (rabbit@rabbitmq3). I dont know how but although the `rabbit@rabbitmq3-feature_flags` said that `user_limit` is not enabled, after I ran `rabbitmqctl forget_cluster_node rabbit@rabbitmq3` on the running node and start the other node it went successfully and became up and cluster is ok too.